# Is Google TV add-on available for Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, google-tv

As per the documentation google-tv updates are available for Android Jellybean version 4.2.2-API level 17. 
But how do i do google-tv app development for Jellybean version. 
I am not able to find google-tv add-on or skins in API level 17.
Currently i am working on API level 13 for google-tv app development. 
Can i test it for API level 17?If yes, how can i create AVD with google-tv skin,for API level 17?

Comment: Have you googled for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Create Google TV AVD in Android](http://oncelinux.blogspot.in/2013/01/googletv-emulator-hang-on-logo-screen.html)

Comment: It is for API level 12.I have already created an avd for API level 12. I was asking about API level 17. Now they say, google TV is supported in API level 17.So i wanted to know how to create a google tv avd for api level 17.